# Не выполняется запрос внутри while

Tags: php

Латаю ферму, используется класс $db, не могу тупо выполнить запрос внутри цикла, данные перебиваются запросом внутри while

```
<?
$db->Query("SELECT * FROM db_task WHERE moder = '1' AND kol_z >= 1 $catt ORDER BY up_date DESC");
while($task = $db->FetchArray()) {

  $db->Query("SELECT id FROM db_task_user WHERE id_task = '$task[id]' LIMIT 1"); // эта штука перебивает похоже $db и выводит пустоту, на самом деле данные есть
  if($db->NumRows() == 0) {//если это и строку выше закомментить, всё норм
  ?>
    Norm<br>
  <? 
  }

} ?>
```

Comment: кто там учил вас писать так `<? ?>`

Comment: @Naumov скрипт не мой, знаю что говнокод, есть решение?

Comment: @Rammsteinik, перепишите запрос к базе так, чтобы остался один единственный запрос вне цикла.

Comment: А что не так с <?

Comment: @Visman думал через INNER JOIN, но никак, так как в доп. таблице db_task_user может и не быть данных

Comment: @Rammsteinik а как насчет LEFT JOIN? :)

Comment: @mJeevas, что-то вот такое http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/

Comment: @Firepro ок, пробую

Comment: @Rammsteinik Изучайте SQL. Любые данные при любых условиях можно получить одним запросом. `select * from db_task A left join db_task_user B on B.id_task=A.id` даст вам записи из первой таблицы вне зависимости от наличия записей во второй. от этого и можно начинать плясать. Там конечно надо как то обыграть limit 1 - но это решаемо, когда точно понятно какую из записей надо взять

Comment: @Mike как же быть при таком раскладе: `select * from db_task A left join db_task_user B on B.id_task=A.id WHERE B.task_user = 1 AND B.status <> 1` , притом в `db_task_user` может и не найтись `task_user = 1`, а данные из этой строки получить надо

Comment: @Rammsteinik Конечно в where не должно быть таких условий. Либо в where пишите `(B.task_user = 1 OR B.task_user is null)` что бы были все записи. То же касается и поля status, которое так же надо проверять на NULL. Либо вообще переносите условие в ON: `select * from db_task A left join db_task_user B on B.id_task=A.id and B.task_user = 1 and B.status<>1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по `$db->FetchArray()`- это одна из детских болезней всех классописателей - [сохранение состояния](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes#statefulness).

`$db` сохраняет внутри себя результат запроса, при вызове в цикле эта переменная перезаписывается, и в итоге всё встаёт колом.

В рамках данного класса проблема не лечится.
Решение - выкинуть эту самопальную писульку и использовать PDO.

Хотя конечно вложенный запрос в любом случае - зло, и его надо переписывать на джойн.

Comment: это понял давно, как увидел класс, используя его нет решения?

Comment: @Ипатьев, такая проблема и у `mysql_*` присутствует :)

Comment: Как раз дописал строчку про это. про вложенные запросы можно забыть. единственный вариант - переписать на джойн, как советуют выше.

Comment: @Visman ни разу. Не надо путать магическое соединение с БД (которое там есть) с персистивным результатом запроса (которого там нет и никогда не было). Результат всегда явно хранится в переменной типа ресурс и перезапишется только если программист сам это сделает.

Comment: Что значит ни разу? Если внутри цикла по `mysql_fetch_assoc` разместить другой запрос к базе, то цикл сломается.

Comment: @Visman Если внутри цикла по mysql_fetch_assoc *догадаться присвоить результат другого запроса переменной с тем же именем*,     то да - цикл сломается ;)

Comment: Не было там одинаковых переменных. Внутри цикла вызывалась функция, в которой был запрос к базе. При использовании функций `mysql_*`, получал некорректную работу цикла. При замене функций на `mysqli_*`, скрипт начинал работать корректно.

Comment: @Visman *"Внутри цикла вызывалась функция"* - рекомендую прочитать мой ответ. В нем объясняется, почему такая функция не будет работать, независимо от используемого API